# function not returning expected list

Tags: python, list, function

I have 3 lists:

```
members = ['Alex', 'Danny', 'Kieran', 'Zoe', 'Caroline']
visitors = ['Scott', 'Helen', 'Raj', 'Danny']
signups = ['Helen', 'Scott']
```

The function should return a list of `visitors` who are neither existing nor new members. If there are none, return `None`.

This is my code:

```
def guests(member,signup,visitor):
    visit = []
    for person in visitor:
        if person not in member and signup:
            visit.append(person)
            return visit
        return print("None.")
```

but my output returns `["Scott"]`. I can't seem to figure what i haven't done right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two things wrong here.

First

```
if person not in member and signup:
```

This interpreted by python in two steps.  "person not in member" and then "signup", signup is "True" as long as signup is not empty.  So it will trigger also on 'Scott'.

Instead you want:

```
if person not in member and person not in signup:
```

Second your return visit is inside the loop, so it will return the list as soon as the first element is discovered.

You need something like:

```
return visit if visit else "None."
```

Comment: `@Christian` Thank you for the simple overview of what needed to be changed.

Comment: I have one question with `return visit if visit`

Comment: `@christian`  is this essentially asking: if there is a list called `visit`, then just return it. otherwise return `none`?

Comment: @TKTK It is using the ternary structure:   true_value if boolean_expression else false_value. 
 A list is true if it is non-empty.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you return after the first value you get and secondly you might wanna change
`if person not in member and signup` to `if person not in member and person not in signup`

```
members = ['Alex', 'Danny', 'Kieran', 'Zoe', 'Caroline']
visitors = ['Scott', 'Helen', 'Raj', 'Danny']
signups = ['Helen', 'Scott']
def guests(member,signup,visitor):
    visit = []
    for person in visitor:
        if person not in member and person not in signup:
            visit.append(person)
    return visit
print(guests(members,signups,visitors))
```

Answer (score 1):

`person not in member and signup` is evaluated as `(person not in member) and (signup)`.

When `person` is 'Scott', the first part is `True`, and the second part (`signup`) is a non-empty list, so it is evaluated as `True` in boolean context, so the whole condition is `True`.

Then, you `return` immediately the output without further looping.

You meant:

```
def guests(member,signup,visitor):
    visit = []
    for person in visitor:
        if person not in member and person not in signup:
            visit.append(person)
    return visit if len(visit) != 0 else None
```

Comment: instead of `if len(visit) != 0` it's better to use just `if visit` as per PEP8 recommendations. Although if it was my function I would return empty list, not `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong, you return the value of the list after the first occurrence of a person that had signed up and is not a member, you should fix the indentation to:

```
def guests(member,signup,visitor):
    visit = []
    for person in visitor:
        if person not in member and person not in signup:
            visit.append(person)
    return visit if len(visit) != 0 else None
```

Also, note how I've changed your return value. You shouldn't return `Print('None')` because while it will return None eventually (As print returns None, it's not a best practice).

Answer (score 0):

@YashShah and @ThierryLathuille explain in their answers why your code does not work. I would suggest a different approach, using sets

```
members = ['Alex', 'Danny', 'Kieran', 'Zoe', 'Caroline']
visitors = ['Scott', 'Helen', 'Raj', 'Danny']
signups = ['Helen', 'Scott']


def get_guests(members,signups,visitors):
    return list(set(visitors).difference(set(members).union(set(signups))))
    # alternative:
    # return list(set(visitors) - (set(members)|set(signups)))

print(get_guests(members, signups, visitors))
```

output

`['Raj']`